# Getting count of repeating users in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a very large index of shopper actions, and I want to extract count of repeating users from that index. I want just count and no other info. If I use min_doc_count with terms aggregation, I can be never sure of the result as there is no upper limit on number of repeating users that I will have and terms need a size parameter. Is there any way I can use min_doc_count as filter and get count of repeating users ?

Comment: providing `size:0` in aggregation will fetch you all the buckets.

Comment: @Richa Size 0 has been removed from ES 5.x

Comment: Thnxx. I was not aware of this.

Comment: Is You'r id's incremental ? if so you can use histogram aggregation.